# Adding dropdown elements dynamically with redactor.js

Tags: redactor

I'm using Redactor and need to dynamically add elements to a custom dropdown menu. I can't find any way of doing this in the documentation - does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible if you use this:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
   focus: true,
   buttonsAdd: ['|', 'button1'],
   buttonsCustom: {
      button1: {
         title: 'Button',
         callback: function(buttonName, buttonDOM, buttonObject) { /* … */ },
         dropdown: {
             alignleft: {
                title: lang.align_left,
                func: 'alignmentLeft'
             },
             aligncenter: {
                title: lang.align_center,
                func: 'alignmentCenter'
             }
         }
      }
   }
});
```